# Как получить список уведомлений VkApi notifications?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь вызвать метод notifications в VkApi в приложение, чтоб получить список уведомлений , но в логах получаю API errorVKError (code: 15; ; Access denied: no access to call this method). Подскажите ,что не так делаю?

```
VKRequest request = new VKRequest("get", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.COUNT, 1000));
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
      super.onComplete(response);
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(VKError error) {
      String err = error.toString();
      Log.e("VK", "err " + err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, у Вас нет необходимых прав доступа.

Это понятно из:

1. Текст ошибки `code: 15; ; Access denied: no access to call this method` В переводе `Код: 15; ; Доступ запрещен: нет прав на вызов этого метода`
2. Код ошибки и [документация](https://vk.com/dev/errors).

[image: скриншот из документации]

3. Находим в той же документации описание [метода](https://vk.com/dev/notifications.get). И видим, что, действительно, нужен доступ.
   [image: скриншот из документации 2]

Приблизительный путь к решению: в этом месте `VKSdk.login(Activity runningActivity, String... scope);` в `scope` добавить `524288` (как числовое значение).

Comment: @EnjoFlash прочитайте внимательно эту статью https://vk.com/dev/permissions

Comment: @EnjoFlash я обновил ответ, так, чтобы он наводил на решение, если Вы еще не нашли сами - ознакомьтесь)